# Differences between and when to use Map vs Record

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to map some Java code which uses Map's to Typescript code.
My initial thought was to use Map's in Typescript but for the interface I was creating this did not work out. Instead I found Records which seemed to emulate Java's Map's perfectly.

My main question is when should I use Typescript's Maps over Records and when should I use Typescripts Records over Maps?

How do they work differently?

```
viewMappings: Record<string, String[]>;
viewMappings: Map<String, String[]>;
```

for example

I expect these to work in an interface with my State very similarly but they do not and am looking for documentation of the differences of the two.

Comment: [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) is a data class in JS that can use any kind of object as a key, while `Record` is just a *type definition* that describes an object, where the keys have to be JS object keys (string, number, or symbol).

Answer (score 29):

Record is defined as

```
type Record<K extends keyof any, T> = {
    [P in K]: T;
}
```

While `Map` is a native JS ES6 data structure. Record is merely a representative way of saying, "this object is going to be used a key, value map of a specific data type". It's a plain object created using `{}`. The `Map` object on the other hands has some unique characteristics described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and needs to be instantiated as `new Map()`

Answer (score 15):

The significant difference for me is that with a Record a key lookup does not optionally return undefined which simplifies my code when I know that keys cannot be missing.

Comment: This is not true. An unknown property of a record also returns `undefined` like an unknown value of a map, [see this TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBARuBcECUCmBjA9mAJgHgM4BcwBLAOwHMAaCEgVwFsokwA+CAXggG8AoCCAMzRp4AJm4BfANzd0JXGgA2SAHQK0ZABQwwywWgCU02fKWr1W8MpC5M-Q9xlo5+CHRAAHAIztqSAO4QALIeGvZuXsq4SPgaAOQgsVSeYR6ekdFxUIkQIvbGiipqmuFpZBkARCDl+vqOcgVmxanKZTHlAF7V+kA)

Comment: @JenniferKiesel Presumably he is talking about the type, not the actual JavaScript output. [Example Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgU1HAJgLhgJSSVAeaOASzAHMAaGMAVwFsAjBOAPhgF4YBvAKBhgDMQIDACZuAXwDc3bqEixBwqnUZx28HKgB0imXOgxaAQwAO6sAgDuMALKmCUYmUo0GTZgAoAlNOMmtEAhQHgDk9EZwIZQAjD564AbhcBiuqup+WqRBoUkhPkA)

Comment: @robere2 Seems so. That makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

Lots of (correct!) answers to this question, but no guidelines as to when to use either.

`Record` (or regular objects) is usually going to be faster, and a good choice for anything internal to your application. Especially for cases where you know what kind of keys will appear.

`Map` is better if you want non-string keys, including numbers and objects. It's also better for user-input as it doesn't suffer from the same prototype polution issues.

Comment: No disagreement on the separation guideline, but the non-string keys point doesn't apply: Record<string|number|CustomType,number>. Map doesn't provide development-time type safety, Record does. This is why we use TypeScript. Of course with generic Maps we get the best of both worlds, at least in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

Given this is a TS question. The correct answer is:

#### `Record`

`Record` is a shorthand for `{ [P in K]: T }` where `P` **must be a `string` (or a `symbol`)**. You can use other types in `P`, but they will be converted to `string` using the built-in method `toString()`.

```js
const testObject = {};
const obj: Record<any, string> = {
  1: 'hello',
  2: 'world',
  [testObject]: 'test',
};

console.log(obj[1]) // 'hello'
console.log(obj['1']) // 'hello'

console.log(obj[testObject]) // 'test'
console.log(obj['[object Object]']) // 'test'
console.log(obj[[/* an empty array*/]]) // 'test'
```

#### `Map`

A map is a key-value store. It does the same job as a normal object but accepts any value as the key.

```js
const testObject = {};
const map = new Map<any, string>();
map.set(1, 'hello');
map.set(1, 'world');
map.set(testObject, 'test');

console.log(obj.get(1)) // 'hello'
console.log(obj.get('1')) // undefined

console.log(obj[testObject]) // 'test'
console.log(obj['[object Object]']) // undefined
console.log(obj[[/* an empty array*/]]) // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Record requires you to use all values from K and T.
Imagine enum A and enum B
Record<A,B> will make sure, that if A or B source values in enums will change, the code wont compile, unless you update the Record.

Answer (score 0):

Record is a TS utility type, Map is an ES6 data structure that has built in methods. So in a way, a Record an interface whereas a Map may implement a Record (I’ll verify and come back to this).

Overall, it is slightly easier to get a list of keys, values, or entries using Map over Record.

Answer (score 0):

**Map**: It is used to map **a value to a value**.

**Record**: It is used to map **a type to a type**.

Comment: This is wrong. This is TS question and javascript does not have `Record` type, the record is only a shorthand for object thus its keys must be a primitive. Map can have any value as a key